# How exactly will I set ymin and ymax in geom_ribbon to create the desired graph?

Tags: r

I am trying to recreate this graph:

[image]

I know I am suppose to be using `geom_ribbon`, or at least I believe so, but I am little confused on exactly how to use it correctly.

This is currently what I have and its generated output:

[image]

I have the the line representing the mean wage across ages, but how do I incorporate the shaded area as seen in the image I provided? I am particularly confused on how to set the ymin and ymax for `geom_ribbon`, if that is even what I should be doing. I am using the CPS85 data set from mosaicData, for reference.

Comment: Its a bit difficult to say without knowing what type of smoothing approach was taken in the original plot. You can get close to that original by setting alpha=0 on the geom_point() and changing the facet_wrap to facet_grid. However, this doesn't help with the main problem, which is replicating the smooth. You are using `geom_smooth()`, which, without further arguments, will by default using `loess`, but that does not appear to be the smoothing approach used in the original plot

Comment: If you knew the smoothing approach used in the original, you could either set the geom_smooth() arguments to match that smooth, and set se=T, or you could use that smoothing approach to predict the actual values and use the se from the model to estimate lower and upper bounds, and then use geom_ribbon with those lower (ymin) and upper (ymax) bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `geom_smoth()` function.
Add the following line to your ggplot defintion.

```
geom_smooth(se=TRUE, method = 'loess', formula = "y~x", span=0.5)
```

Adjusting the span parameter with change how curvy the smoothing is.